# Classification with multiple features?

Tags: classification, cluster-analysis, prediction, feature-selection, auc

I have:

1) 2 groups of subjects (controls and cancer patients)

2) a group of features, for each of them.

I want to find the feature, or which combination of which features, discriminate best between the two groups.

I have started with evaluation of AUC, then with some k means clustering, but I don't know how to combine features for the classification.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use some method of feature importance evaluation. There is many different way to test importance of features. At first, in my opinion, easy one is Random Forest classifier. This model has "build-in" feature importance evaluation during training, based on out-of-bag error. Tree-based classifiers must evaluate gain of information after getting value of feature in training process.

You can also test feature importance by checking model score by modifying data set, i.e using backward elimination strategy.

You can use also PCA or statistic tests. Finally you can also looking for dependency between feature to remove from your data feature that not provide enough information.